# How to take value of JComboBox value that is inside JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, awt, jcombobox

I have tried this part of code to get values from a `JComboBox` that is inside of a `JTable`, but it doesn't work!

I want to get the value of selected cell in order to insert into DB.

```
package fx;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

public class ComboInTable extends JFrame {
   private static JFrame jFrame;
    public ComboInTable() throws HeadlessException {
        jFrame=this;
        JTable table=new JTable();
        DefaultTableModel model= (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
        model.addColumn("A",new Object[]{"item1"});
        model.addColumn("B",new Object[]{"item2"});
        JScrollPane scrollPane=new JScrollPane(table);

        String[] value1=new String[]{"1","2","3"};
        String[] value2=new String[]{"a","b","c"};

        TableColumn col0=table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
        TableColumn col1=table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);

        col0.setCellEditor(new MyComboBoxEditor(value1));
        col0.setCellRenderer(new MyComboBoxRenderer(value1));
        col1.setCellEditor(new MyComboBoxEditor(value2));
        col1.setCellRenderer(new MyComboBoxRenderer(value2));
        JComboBox comboBox=new JComboBox(value1);
       comboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
           @Override
           public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
               if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
               {
                   System.out.println(e.getItem());
               }
           }
       });
        jFrame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        jFrame.add(scrollPane);
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jFrame.setSize(400, 400);
        jFrame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ComboInTable comboInTable=new ComboInTable();

    }

}
```

I have `MyComboBoxEditor` and `MyComboBoxRenderer` classes.

```
package fx;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import java.awt.*;

public class MyComboBoxRenderer extends JComboBox implements TableCellRenderer {
    public MyComboBoxRenderer(String[] items) {
        super( items);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        if(isSelected){
            setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
            super.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
        }
        else {
            setForeground(table.getForeground());
            setBackground(table.getBackground());

        }
        setSelectedItem(value);
        return this;
    }
}






package fx;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;

public class MyComboBoxEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {
    public MyComboBoxEditor(String[] items) {
        super(new JComboBox(items));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have tried this part of code to get values from a JComboBox that is inside of a JTable,

You don't get the value from the combo box.

You get the value from the `JTable` using the `getValueAt(...)` method.

I also have no idea why you are creating a custom renderer and editor. Just use the default renderer/editor provided by the table.

Start by reading the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html). You will find an example that shows how to use a combo box as an editor.